# No tests found for given includes:

Tags: java, testing, gradle, groovy, junit

I'm trying to run a simple test that's in my Test class from IDE (Intellij IDEA) and error that pops out is:

```
No tests found for given includes: org.sample.Test.test
```

Same thing is happening when I try to run it from command-line. In Intellij, I've set up `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner` to `Gradle Test Runner` and I have `@Test` on my method. Also, I can't run any test (from some other project), so I suppose that it's some configuration problem.

Can someone point me to something, what can I be doing wrong ?

Comment: What does your test class look like?

Comment: Idea and Gradle are sensitive to the placement of the test classes. I.e. they should be located below src/test/java. (Unless you have explicitly configured paths to different locations, not usually a good idea.) Also, make sure you have at least one valid test method, i.e public void with no args annotated with @Test. Are you sure that your test class has imported the right Test class and not something else by accident? You should post an example of a test class that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer. On my Test class, I have @Category annotation. If I remove that one, my tests work, but I still don't know why. For example, on my colleague's IDE, same tests, but with @Category annotation work. It's a bit frustrating.

But, thanks for such a fast responses.